# Couldn't get Width of a view at runtime using databinding

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-databinding

I have an ImageView in my xml  that is using databinding library and its height is "match_parent" , Now I have a requirement of changing its height at runtime, but when I am getting its width , its always giving me 0 , How to get its actual width dimension ?

*I have this below ImageView in my xml:*

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:imageUrl="@{data.bannerImage}"
    tools:src="@drawable/iop"
    android:src="@drawable/iop"/>
```

and  I am setting its height to the ratio of width using the below java code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

   mBinding.notifyChange();
   mBinding.bannerImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout() {
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mBinding.bannerImage.getLayoutParams();
           Log.e("tag","mBinding.bannerImage.getWidth()=="+mBinding.tvReviews.getWidth());
           params.height= (int)(mBinding.tvReviews.getWidth()/1.75);
           mBinding.bannerImage.setLayoutParams(params);
           Log.e("tag,"params.height=="+params.height);
           mBinding.bannerImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
           mBinding.notifyPropertyChanged(com.webkul.mobikulmp.BR.bannerImage);
       }
   });
}
```

here **mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_seller_profile)**;, // replace your xml here, but I am always getting 0 returned for mBinding.bannerImage.getWidth(). I have also tried giving fix width to the ImageView, and also getting its width on some button click listener but all in vain.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the Width and height of View at runtime

```
 int Height, Width;
    final ImageView imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = imgview .getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imgview .getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            Height = imgview .getMeasuredHeight();
            Width = imgview .getMeasuredWidth();
            tv.setText("Height: " + Height + " Width: " + Width);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

bcoz you add ViewTreeObserver for ImageView and get width of "tvReviews" TextView. so change the code like below

```
mBinding.bannerImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mBinding.bannerImage.getLayoutParams();
            Log.e("tag","mBinding.bannerImage.getWidth()=="+mBinding.bannerImage.getWidth());
            params.height= (int)(mBinding.bannerImage.getWidth()/1.75);
            mBinding.bannerImage.setLayoutParams(params);
            Log.e("tag,"params.height=="+params.height);
                    mBinding.bannerImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            mBinding.notifyPropertyChanged(com.webkul.mobikulmp.BR.bannerImage);
        }
    });
```